# Why is variable substitution only recommended for values that wont change during lifetime of a widget?

Tags: dojo

Regarding Variable Substitution in Dojo

> **Variable Substitution:** 
>   A template can have values set on DOM rendering
>   though the use of a simple variable placeholder syntax, which looks
>   like this:
>
> ${property}

According to the documentation

> Variable substitution in a template is only recommended for values
>   that will not be changed during the lifetime of the widget. In other
>   words, if you expect to be able to set the value of a property in a
>   widget during the lifetime of your application programmatically, we
>   recommend instead using your widget's postCreate method to set any
>   variables programmatically through your widget's set() method.

Can someone explain why this recommendation is made?

Comment: This answers could help you out to answer your question http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Clarification-on-templates-td3929384.html

Comment: Probably for people expecting two way data binding like in `angularjs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable substitution in Dojo has no binding.
This mean it wont change even if you change the actual value of the variable.

If a binding is needed, then you can use an attach point and a setter for that value. It will then have a binding and the UI will be updated with the new value.
Something like this:

```
    _setLabelAttr : {
        node : "_tplLabelNode",
        type : "innerHTML"
    },
```

Will bind the `innerHTML` of attach point `_tplLabelNode` to the "label" property of the widget.
So `widget.set('label', 'foo');` will update the UI.

However `<div>${label}</div>` has no bind. `${label}` will be replaced at creation of the widget and will never be updated